# DVD-drive detected by BIOS and UEFI but not by Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hardware, cd-drive

I have build a new tower containing;

Asrock Z77 extreme4                     (motherboard)
Core i7                                 (processor)
Hitachi LGE-DMGH 12 L (B) GH15F SATA    (SATA DVD-drive)

Problem is;

BIOS and UEFI has no problems detecting the DVD-drive but
it is not detected by Ubuntu 12.04. It is not present in
`/etc/fstab` or `/etc/mtab`.

I have now upgraded to 12.10 but I still have the same problem...
-any ideas... ?

Below is the contents of fstab and mtab.

Thanks for all your help.

fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f007bc60-da4c-4f36-99a7-77083c5f3654 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=5d59949c-aed9-442a-877d-5abf1ccaadc3 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

mtab:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/tom/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=tom 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

SORRY MISREAD YOUR QUESTION.
    NEW ANSWER
    I have this exact board w/Slackware64-14.0 installed
    My etc/fstab

```
/dev/sda1       /boot/efi       vfat    defaults,noatime,discard        0   2
/dev/sda2       /               ext4    defaults,noatime,discard        0   1
/dev/sda3       /home           ext4    defaults,noatime,discard        0   1
/dev/sda4       swap            swap    defaults,noatime,discard        0   0
/dev/sr0        /media/dvd      auto    noauto,users,ro,comment=x-gvfs-show     0   0
```